# Handling server-side sync with Codeigniter for Backbone.js

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, backbone.js

How should a Backbone sync aka `RESTful JSON request` be handled on the PHP Codeigniter side?

There's a Ruby example in the manual but I don't know Ruby maybe someone could translate it?

```
def update
  account = Account.find params[:id]
  account.update_attributes params
  render :json => account
end
```

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used it, personally, but you might want to check out Phil Sturgeon's [RESTful server for CodeIgniter](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver).